# Ultimate Aim of Spring-Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

as you may know Spring4 comes with new features, and one of the most important feature among them is Spring-boot.
I am following the links below

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-documentation

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot

Spring-boot feature comes with new class files in `org.springframework.boot.*` to start the Spring application. There are two question comes in mind that

**1-** for JavaSE, I can start-up the spring application with previoues spring versions easly, is the new feature spring-boot is just for simple boot

**2-** for JavaEE, as far as I know Spring-boot is not just for javaSE project, it can start-up web projects as well. So in the future spring-boot works as Application-server (like Glassfish)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Spring Boot only works with Spring 4+, it is technically a different project. What this means is that you can use Spring 4 without any Spring Boot code.

The aim of Spring Boot is to provide an easy way to configure a Spring application by providing sensible defaults and easy configuration options for stuff that is commonly used (and you otherwise have to implemented) over and over again in our applications.

As far as starting up a Java SE application, Spring Boot will easily start the application just like any other Java SE, with the `main` method, and looks something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
//whatever other annotations
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        //do whatever
    }

}
```

In order to use a web environment, Spring Boot uses an embedded servlet container (Tomcat by default, but Jetty is also available). That means that code like:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }

}
```

is enough to get everything started (providing that all the required dependencies are on the classpath).

Seeing working Spring code that is so light, is a breath of fresh air! You no longer need to loads of XML or Java config files, the defaults work great!
Also you can start and stop the whole application from the main method inside your IDE! Sweet!

Comment: If it is different project,is there a way yo start-up spring3 project via spring-boot?

Comment: @mmc18 As far as I know, that is impossible! The are some parts of core of Spring Boot that depend on Spring 4 (like the existence of `@Conditional`)

Comment: I still think that in the future we may be in a situation where we can find ourselves dealing with Spring-boot parameters rather than application itself. I mean there are many specific jar files such as WS, JPA, ..etc.

Comment: @mmc18 I'm sorry but I don't really understand what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: I mean I might spend as time as to run my application in javaee container and via spring-boot.